# is possible get VNC remote server working with KDE/plasma?

Tags: server, kubuntu, vnc, opengl, plasma-5

I'm trying to get running a multiuser remote desktop *Quarantine Mode*, every session running their own instances of kde. At this moment I have configured lightDM with the VNC server running. I can get running Xfce without problems, but Kde crashes on splash. Also from Xfce I can't get OpenGL running (glxinfo does not find anything and says that there's no RGB display).

this is the "incomplete" kde splashscreen backtrace

```
 Application: ksplashqml (ksplashqml), signal: Aborted
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f6fa989f500 (LWP 3441))]

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7f6fa727a700 (LWP 3457)):
#0  __GI___libc_read (nbytes=16, buf=0x7f6fa7279ae0, fd=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c:26
#1  __GI___libc_read (fd=6, buf=buf@entry=0x7f6fa7279ae0, nbytes=nbytes@entry=16) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c:24
#2  0x00007f6fabed070f in read (__nbytes=16, __buf=0x7f6fa7279ae0, __fd=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/unistd.h:44
#3  g_wakeup_acknowledge (wakeup=0x7f6fa0001bc0) at ../../../glib/gwakeup.c:210
#4  0x00007f6fabe885fe in g_main_context_check (context=context@entry=0x7f6f98000c30, max_priority=2147483647, fds=fds@entry=0x7f6f980029e0, n_fds=n_fds@entry=1) at ../../../glib/gmain.c:3695
#5  0x00007f6fabe88a52 in g_main_context_iterate (context=context@entry=0x7f6f98000c30, block=block@entry=1, dispatch=dispatch@entry=1, self=<optimized out>) at ../../../glib/gmain.c:3914
#6  0x00007f6fabe88be3 in g_main_context_iteration (context=0x7f6f98000c30, may_block=may_block@entry=1) at ../../../glib/gmain.c:3978
#7  0x00007f6fae1f7653 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents (this=0x7f6f98000b60, flags=...) at kernel/qeventdispatcher_glib.cpp:424
#8  0x00007f6fae19e5cb in QEventLoop::exec (this=this@entry=0x7f6fa7279cf0, flags=..., flags@entry=...) at ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/global/qflags.h:140
#9  0x00007f6fadfd7a45 in QThread::exec (this=this@entry=0x7f6faeb30d80 <(anonymous namespace)::Q_QGS__q_manager::innerFunction()::holder>) at ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/global/qflags.h:120
#10 0x00007f6faeaadefa in QDBusConnectionManager::run (this=0x7f6faeb30d80 <(anonymous namespace)::Q_QGS__q_manager::innerFunction()::holder>) at qdbusconnection.cpp:178
#11 0x00007f6fadfd8c92 in QThreadPrivate::start (arg=0x7f6faeb30d80 <(anonymous namespace)::Q_QGS__q_manager::innerFunction()::holder>) at thread/qthread_unix.cpp:361
#12 0x00007f6fad19a669 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:479
#13 0x00007f6fadc5d323 in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f6fa834d700 (LWP 3447)):
#0  0x00007f6fadc50c2f in __GI___poll (fds=fds@entry=0x7f6fa834cc28, nfds=nfds@entry=1, timeout=timeout@entry=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007f6facfe6917 in poll (__timeout=-1, __nfds=1, __fds=0x7f6fa834cc28) at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/poll2.h:46
#2  _xcb_conn_wait (c=c@entry=0x56335ee381e0, cond=cond@entry=0x56335ee38220, vector=vector@entry=0x0, count=count@entry=0x0) at ../../src/xcb_conn.c:479
#3  0x00007f6facfe853a in xcb_wait_for_event (c=c@entry=0x56335ee381e0) at ../../src/xcb_in.c:697
#4  0x00007f6fa8f67288 in QXcbEventQueue::run (this=0x56335ee4bf40) at qxcbeventqueue.cpp:228
#5  0x00007f6fadfd8c92 in QThreadPrivate::start (arg=0x56335ee4bf40) at thread/qthread_unix.cpp:361
#6  0x00007f6fad19a669 in start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at pthread_create.c:479
#7  0x00007f6fadc5d323 in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f6fa989f500 (LWP 3441)):
[KCrash Handler]
#7  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#8  0x00007f6fadb60899 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#9  0x00007f6fadf9fa99 in qt_message_fatal (context=..., message=<synthetic pointer>...) at global/qlogging.cpp:1904
#10 QMessageLogger::fatal (this=this@entry=0x7fff8ab69a60, msg=msg@entry=0x7f6fa909b220 "Could not initialize GLX") at global/qlogging.cpp:888
#11 0x00007f6fa9094876 in QGLXContext::init (this=0x56335ee80e70, screen=0x56335ee521f0, share=<optimized out>) at ../../../../../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/global/qlogging.h:91
#12 0x00007f6fa9094d3b in QXcbGlxIntegration::createPlatformOpenGLContext (this=<optimized out>, context=0x7fff8ab69bf0) at qxcbglxintegration.cpp:186
#13 0x00007f6fa8f3ef2f in QXcbIntegration::createPlatformOpenGLContext (this=<optimized out>, context=0x7fff8ab69bf0) at qxcbintegration.cpp:285
#14 0x00007f6fae5c7b31 in QOpenGLContext::create (this=this@entry=0x7fff8ab69bf0) at ../../include/QtGui/5.12.4/QtGui/private/../../../../../src/gui/kernel/qguiapplication_p.h:105
#15 0x00007f6fa9097de1 in QGLXContext::queryDummyContext () at qglxintegration.cpp:701
#16 0x00007f6fa90986bd in QGLXContext::supportsThreading () at qglxintegration.cpp:777
#17 0x00007f6faed78b05 in QSGRenderLoop::instance () at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/5.12.4/QtGui/private/qguiapplication_p.h:105
#18 0x00007f6faedef69a in QQuickWindowPrivate::init (this=0x56335ee37e60, c=0x7f6f98013950, control=0x0) at items/qquickwindow.cpp:560
#19 0x00007f6faf1a2a84 in KQuickAddons::QuickViewSharedEngine::QuickViewSharedEngine (this=0x7f6f98013950, parent=<optimized out>) at ./src/quickaddons/quickviewsharedengine.cpp:141
#20 0x000056335d2a3d60 in SplashWindow::SplashWindow (this=0x7f6f98013950, testing=<optimized out>, window=<optimized out>, theme=...) at ./ksplash/ksplashqml/splashwindow.cpp:40
#21 0x000056335d2a29ce in SplashApp::adoptScreen (this=this@entry=0x7fff8ab69f80, screen=0x56335ee612c0) at ./ksplash/ksplashqml/splashapp.cpp:139
#22 0x000056335d2a320b in SplashApp::SplashApp (this=0x7fff8ab69f80, argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at ./ksplash/ksplashqml/splashapp.cpp:76
#23 0x000056335d2a2026 in main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=0x7fff8ab6a0e8) at ./ksplash/ksplashqml/main.cpp:108
[Inferior 1 (process 3441) detached]
```

I have Kubuntu 19.10 eoan ermine. I'm using AMDGPUpro 20.10 preview for video (R9Fury) in the host machine (The local user works pretty well). The final "goal" is to get kdenlive running (mp4 hardware encoding in particular), so some other guys edit videos from outside, and this computer renders, while I'm at my session doing another boring stuff.
I'm downloading symbols now to try to debug this, but I think that the problem is more "subtle" and is just the remote server isn't finding libGL.

Thanks for reading, and please ask if more info is needed.