# Use KDE Plasma desktop over VNC on Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, remote-desktop, vnc

In short: how I can I use the Plasma desktop environment over VNC?

---

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with KDE Plasma 5.24.7 (the "Kubuntu" image install).

Logging in to the machine physically is fine and the UI looks awesome. Now I want to access the machine using something like remote desktop, I figured VNC is the best option.

So I install and run `tightvncserver` on the machine, basically following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-20-04):

```bash
sudo apt install tightvncserver
tightvncserver :1
```

I can already remote in now, from Windows, using the RealVNC client. However, the screen is just empty.

So I go back to my machine to change `~/.vnc/xstartup` and make it look like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &
```

After restarting the VNC server I can now remote in and actually see and use a desktop, but the environment is of course now Xfce, instead of KDE Plasma like I use with physical access.
**How can I use KDE when using VNC? Which `xstartup` command would I need?**

---

I have already tried `startkde &`, `startx &` and `startplasma-x11 &` but all of those just result in a plain grey screen.

Specifically I found [this guide](https://bytexd.com/how-to-install-configure-vnc-server-on-ubuntu/#configure-vnc-to-use-kde-plasma-desktop) which suggests the following for `xstartup`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# Start up the standard system desktop
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
/usr/bin/cinnamon-session
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
x-window-manager &
```

Now I get the Plasma loading splash screen on VNC connect, but after a few seconds the screen becomes black. The full error log for this from TightVNC:

```
03/01/24 11:37:50 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.10
03/01/24 11:37:50 Copyright (C) 2000-2009 TightVNC Group
03/01/24 11:37:50 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
03/01/24 11:37:50 All Rights Reserved.
03/01/24 11:37:50 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
03/01/24 11:37:50 Desktop name 'X' (canis-major:1)
03/01/24 11:37:50 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
03/01/24 11:37:50 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
qt.qpa.xcb: xrender >= 0.5 required to create pixmap cursors
kdeinit5: preparing to launch '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5/klauncher'
kdeinit5: Launched KLauncher, pid = 32195, result = 0
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 2 (BadValue), sequence: 355, resource id: 32, major code: 53 (CreatePixmap), minor code: 0
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 9 (BadDrawable), sequence: 356, resource id: 8388619, major code: 55 (CreateGC), minor code: 0
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 9 (BadDrawable), sequence: 357, resource id: 8388619, major code: 55 (CreateGC), minor code: 0
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
kdeinit5: opened connection to :1
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
Initializing  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_style.so"
kdeinit5: Got SETENV 'GTK_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk/gtkrc:/home/robert/.gtkrc:/home/robert/.config/gtkrc' from launcher.
kdeinit5: Got SETENV 'GTK2_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:/home/robert/.gtkrc-2.0:/home/robert/.config/gtkrc-2.0' from launcher.
QDBusConnection: error: could not send signal to service "" path "//home/robert/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals" interface "org.kde.kconfig.notify" member "ConfigChanged": Invalid object path: //home/robert/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals
Initializing  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_fonts.so"
Initializing  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_mouse.so"
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
kdeinit5: Got SETENV 'XCURSOR_THEME=breeze_cursors' from launcher.
kdeinit5: Got SETENV 'XCURSOR_SIZE=24' from launcher.
org.kde.plasma.session: process job  "kcminit_startup" finished with exit code  0
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
Warning: Setting a new default format with a different version or profile after the global shared context is created may cause issues with context sharing.
The X11 connection broke: Unsupported extension used (code 2)
XIO:  fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server ":1"
      after 183 requests (5 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
Qt: Session management error: networkIdsList argument is NULL
Xlib:  extension "MIT-SCREEN-SAVER" missing on display ":1".
kdeinit5: Got SETENV 'SESSION_MANAGER=local/canis-major:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/32251,unix/canis-major:/tmp/.ICE-unix/32251' from launcher.
kdeinit5: Got SETENV 'SESSION_MANAGER=local/canis-major:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/32251,unix/canis-major:/tmp/.ICE-unix/32251' from launcher.
Initializing  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_kgamma.so"
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/powerdevil.desktop" ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/org_kde_powerdevil")
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/baloo_file.desktop" ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/baloo_file")
Initializing  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_touchpad.so"
kcm_touchpad: Using X11 backend
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/org.kde.plasmashell.desktop" ("/usr/bin/plasmashell")
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/xembedsniproxy.desktop" ("/usr/bin/xembedsniproxy")
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1.desktop" ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1")
kwin_platform_x11_standalone: Compositing disabled: no composite extension available
kwin_core: Compositing is not possible
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/kaccess.desktop" ("/usr/bin/kaccess")
Baloo File Indexing has been disabled
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/pam_kwallet_init.desktop" ("/usr/share/libpam-kwallet-common/pam_kwallet_init")
kf.config.core: "\"fsrestore1\" - conversion of \"0,0,0,0\" to QRect failed"
kf.config.core: "\"fsrestore2\" - conversion of \"0,0,0,0\" to QRect failed"
kwin_core: Failed to update gamma ramp for output KWin::X11PlaceholderOutput(0x55c9cb2ee1e0, name="Placeholder-0", geometry=QRect(0,0 1920x1080), scale=1)
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 536, resource id: 20971525, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
kde.xembedsniproxy: could not load damage extension. Quitting
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 544, resource id: 20971526, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
Xlib XKB extension major= 1  minor= 0
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
New PolkitAgentListener  0x5613b941ae00
Adding new listener  PolkitQt1::Agent::Listener(0x5613b94433a0) for  0x5613b941ae00
Listener online
X server has not matching XKB extension

qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 564, resource id: 41943045, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
Authentication agent result: true
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/pulseaudio.desktop" ("/usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11")
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/org.kde.discover.notifier.desktop" ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/DiscoverNotifier")
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/gmenudbusmenuproxy.desktop" ("/usr/bin/gmenudbusmenuproxy")
AUDIT: Wed Jan  3 11:37:51 2024: 32132 Xtightvnc: client 12 rejected from local host
Failure: Module initialization failed
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/xdg-user-dirs.desktop" ("/usr/bin/xdg-user-dirs-update")
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/org.kde.kdeconnect.daemon.desktop" ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kdeconnectd")
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
org.kde.powerdevil: org.kde.powerdevil.discretegpuhelper.hasdualgpu failed
org.kde.powerdevil: org.kde.powerdevil.chargethresholdhelper.getthreshold failed ""
org.kde.powerdevil: org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper.brightness failed
kf.plasma.quick: Applet preload policy set to 1
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/geoclue-demo-agent.desktop" ("/usr/libexec/geoclue-2.0/demos/agent")
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop" ("/usr/libexec/at-spi-bus-launcher", "--launch-immediately")
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/im-launch.desktop" ("/usr/bin/sh", "-c", "if [ \"x$XDG_SESSION_TYPE\" = \"xwayland\" ] ; then exec env IM_CONFIG_CHECK_ENV=1 im-launch true; fi")
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/spice-vdagent.desktop" ("/usr/bin/spice-vdagent")
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/kup-daemon.desktop" ("/usr/bin/kup-daemon")
kf.notifications: env says KDE is running but SNI unavailable -- check KDE_FULL_SESSION and XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/snap-userd-autostart.desktop" ("/usr/bin/snap", "userd", "--autostart")
org.kde.powerdevil: DPMS extension not available
qt.qpa.xcb: XKeyboard extension not present on the X server
kup.daemon: "Kup is not enabled, enable it from the system settings module. You can do that by running kcmshell5 kup"
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 612, resource id: 58720261, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
org.kde.powerdevil: Handle button events action could not check for screen configuration
org.kde.powerdevil: The profile  "AC" tried to activate "DimDisplay" a non-existent action. This is usually due to an installation problem, a configuration problem, or because the action is not supported
org.kde.powerdevil: The profile  "AC" tried to activate "DPMSControl" a non-existent action. This is usually due to an installation problem, a configuration problem, or because the action is not supported
kf.notifications: env says KDE is running but SNI unavailable -- check KDE_FULL_SESSION and XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
kf.notifications: env says KDE is running but SNI unavailable -- check KDE_FULL_SESSION and XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
org.kde.powerdevil: org.kde.powerdevil.chargethresholdhelper.getthreshold failed ""
org.kde.kscreen: Failed to request backend: unknown error
org.kde.powerdevil: Handle button events action could not check for screen configuration
QObject::connect(QObject, ConfigMonitor::Private): invalid nullptr parameter
org.kde.kscreen: Failed to request backend: unknown error
qml: PlasmaExtras.ScrollArea is deprecated. Use PlasmaComponents3.ScrollView instead.
trying to show an empty dialog
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:118:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:118:19: QML Loader: Binding loop detected for property "height"
The X11 connection broke: Unsupported extension used (code 2)
XIO:  fatal IO error 2 (No such file or directory) on X server ":1"
      after 478 requests (441 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 819, resource id: 46137350, major code: 15 (QueryTree), minor code: 0
kf.notifications: env says KDE is running but SNI unavailable -- check KDE_FULL_SESSION and XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
kf.notifications: env says KDE is running but SNI unavailable -- check KDE_FULL_SESSION and XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP

03/01/24 11:37:53 Got connection from client 127.0.0.1
03/01/24 11:37:53 Using protocol version 3.8
03/01/24 11:37:53 Full-control authentication passed by 127.0.0.1
03/01/24 11:37:53 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 24
03/01/24 11:37:53 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
03/01/24 11:37:53 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
03/01/24 11:37:53 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
03/01/24 11:37:53 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
03/01/24 11:37:53 Using zlib encoding for client 127.0.0.1
03/01/24 11:37:53 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
03/01/24 11:37:53 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 127.0.0.1
03/01/24 11:37:53 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
03/01/24 11:37:53 Pixel format for client 127.0.0.1:
03/01/24 11:37:53   8 bpp, depth 6
03/01/24 11:37:53   true colour: max r 3 g 3 b 3, shift r 4 g 2 b 0
03/01/24 11:37:53 Using raw encoding for client 127.0.0.1
03/01/24 11:37:53 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 24
03/01/24 11:37:53 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
03/01/24 11:37:53 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
03/01/24 11:37:53 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
03/01/24 11:37:53 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
03/01/24 11:37:53 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
03/01/24 11:37:53 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 127.0.0.1
03/01/24 11:37:53 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
03/01/24 11:37:53 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 24
03/01/24 11:37:53 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 16
03/01/24 11:37:53 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 22
03/01/24 11:37:53 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 21
03/01/24 11:37:53 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding 15
03/01/24 11:37:53 Using zlib encoding for client 127.0.0.1
03/01/24 11:37:53 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -314
03/01/24 11:37:53 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 127.0.0.1
03/01/24 11:37:53 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unknown encoding -223
03/01/24 11:37:53 Pixel format for client 127.0.0.1:
03/01/24 11:37:53   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
03/01/24 11:37:53   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
03/01/24 11:37:53   no translation needed
kdeconnect.core: Could not query capabilities from notifications server
qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 857, resource id: 8388622, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code: 0
03/01/24 11:38:25 Client 127.0.0.1 gone
03/01/24 11:38:25 Statistics:
03/01/24 11:38:25   key events received 2, pointer events 37
03/01/24 11:38:25   framebuffer updates 683, rectangles 39590, bytes 9729171
03/01/24 11:38:25     cursor shape updates 3, bytes 1092
03/01/24 11:38:25     raw rectangles 1, bytes 17292
03/01/24 11:38:25     zlib rectangles 39586, bytes 9710787
03/01/24 11:38:25   raw bytes equivalent 820767620, compression ratio 84.370986
```

---

Similar questions that are close but of no help to me:

- [is possible get VNC remote server working with KDE/plasma?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225830/is-possible-get-vnc-remote-server-working-with-kde-plasma)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548704/xstartup-for-kde